# WeMos D1 Errors

Tags: arduino, esp8266

I have been trying to get my WeMos D1 to work. I spent all day trying to get Arduino IDE to compile. I finally get it to, but when I try to upload it to my WeMos D1 it gives me these errors...

```
error: Failed to open COM3
error: espcomm_open failed
error: espcomm_upload_mem failed
```

The WeMos is connected to COM3 and the drivers are installed. I am not sure what to do next.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had to go to Tools-->Port--> COM6 (could be something else for you depending on how your USB ports are defined).  When I selected a port from the dropdown, which wasn't COM3, it then uploaded the sketch and all was good (provided your code actually works!)

Answer (score 0):

Try using platformio ide. It has very good support for wemos.